# Button width in react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am starting learning react-native-paper, i am not sure how to fix button width, currently it fills whole parent container.

```
    <View>
        <Button 
        icon="camera" 
        mode="contained" 
        onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
        contentStyle={styles.btn}
        >
            Press me
        </Button>
    </View>



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    btn: {
        width: 30
    }
})
```

This is not working and button is still full width.
Need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the width of `Button` directly using `style` props and adding `width` to it.

```
<Button 
   icon="camera" 
   mode="contained" 
   onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
   style={{ width: 100 }}
>
  Press me
</Button>
```

Comment: thanks it working, but what is the use of "contentStyle"

Comment: MaterialBottomTab doesn't support contentStyle. Even docs of React-native-paper and react-navigation doesnt mentioned about contentStyle

Comment: I don't like this approach. There should be a better way and should be provided by react-native-paper. The image which they show doesn't have the full width though.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1979#issuecomment-654310158

Comment: The style prop on the Botton doesnt actually work

Answer (score 1):

You can make it fit to content dynamically without defining number or width.  You can override style attribute **alignSelf** to 'flex-start'. Here is the example:

```
      <Button
        mode="outlined"
        onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
        style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}
      >
        Save
      </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your View tag is a container for the button, the button needs its own View tag with the styles prop called there.

```
    <View>
      <View style={styles.btn}>
       <Button 
          icon="camera" 
          mode="contained" 
          onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
       >
        Press me
       </Button>
      </View>
    </View>



    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      btn: {
        width: 30
      },
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).